# Controllers and IDisposable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, idisposable

If I make a controller implement `IDisposable`, I assume that the `Dispose` method still won't be invoked by the GC. So that means I would have to add:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!isDalDisposed)
    {
        isDalDisposed = true;
        if (disposing)
            DAL.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I have read that using `Object.Finalize` is bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

The issue I have is that my "services" are created in the default constructor which does not permit me to use a `using` statement to control the lifetime of each service. So, what would be the correct way to handle this issue?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: what kind of controllers are you talking about? In WebAPI, controllers are instantiated per request, so no need to dispose explicitly.

Comment: yeah I am talking about web api controllers. I have some services that are disposable and I instantiate them in the constructor. I need to dispose of them when they are done, but I am trying to find a way of doing it that doesn't use the finalize approach because I read that it is bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web API's `ApiController` has already implemented `IDisposable` and provides convenient virtual method for developers to override, which is the `Dispose(bool)` method you are using. So all you need to do is remove your own boolean flag and just check only `disposing` parameter.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        DAL.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can override `protected void Dispose(bool disposing)`, it would imply that the base class uses the [Disposable pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx), and already implements `IDisposable`.

Just remove the `IDisposable` interface and the `public void Dispose()` method, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you create the service in the constructor?

Since the controller is instantiated per request you can create the service in the action itself within a 'using' block. The lifetime of the service is anways limited to the action.

Comment: And a related possibility would be injecting a service factory into the controller constructor and then using the injected factory within the action to create the service. Note that the injected factory itself should not implement `IDisposable` and therefore need to be disposed. (Though if it did, its disposal would arguably be the responsibility of the injector.)